# Unable to delete with EF

Tags: entity-framework

Found the issue...I had MergeOption.NoTracking set on my context.entity...sigh

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.

```
        var deleteOrders = db.TABLE.Where(x => x.WCCR_ID == WccrId && x.ADAM == null).ToList();
        foreach (var item in deleteOrders)
        {

            db.TABLE.DeleteObject(item);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
```

I tried attaching the item db.Attach(item), but that throws an error 'Object with the same Key already exists'.

thanks for your help. cheers

Comment: Henk, any tips on how to check the tracking status? EF v4.30319 and using ODAC(Oracle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good. Try using:

```
var deleteOrders = db.TABLE.Where(x => x.WCCR_ID == WccrId && x.ADAM == null)
                           .ToList();
        foreach (var item in deleteOrders)
        {
            db.Entry(item).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;            
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
```

**UPDATE**

EF 4.0 uses the `ObjectContext` class.

```
using(YourContext ctx = new YourContext())
{
   ctx.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, System.Data.EntityState.Deleted);
}
```

EF 4.1 uses the `DbContext` class in which the methods like `Set<T>` and `Entry` are defined.

```
using(YourContext ctx = new YourContext())
{
   ctx.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

The NuGet package only includes the EF 4.1 runtime and does not include the Visual Studio item templates for using DbContext with Model First and Database First development.

Download: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26825

Comment: Hi plurby,what version of EF is Entry in?

Comment: Updated my answer to explain in which version of EF Entry is used.

Comment: Plurby, my version shows 4.1.0.0. Is there a config/option somewhere else that I need to set? While learning EF, I've noticed that when I try to use any DbContext that it doesn't work, similiar to .Entry. I just assumed I had an older version, even though I got 4.1 from nuGet. thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer for explaining your EF 4.1 question. See if it helps you.

Comment: big thanks plurby for taking the time to explain these details to me. Much appreciated!